# How can I echo MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Assalammualaikum..
I have database like this:

```
name | subjects | score 
B    | math     | 70 
B    | math     | 80 
B    | scien    | 90 
A    | math     | 80
```

And I have query like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT  name, subject, score 
( 
 CASE subject WHEN @curSubject 
 THEN @curRow := @curRow +1  
 ELSE @curRow :=1 AND @curSubject:= subject END 
)  AS rank 
FROM table GROUP BY name,score ORDER BY name, score desc");
```

If I Select on SQL output from that query just like this:

```
name | subjects | score | rank 
B    | math     | 80    | 1 
B    | math     | 70    | 2 
B    | scien    | 90    | 1 
A    | math     | 80    | 1
```

My problem is, when I will echo using looping php code like this:

while ($array = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
echo $array['rank']'
';
}

output:

```
rank  | rank (not like this)
1     | 1 
1     | 2 
1     | 1 
1     | 1
```

How can the value rank be echoed? Thank you
Wassalammualaikum..

Comment: The function `mysql_fetch_array()` fetches a single row. If you are trying to display more than one rank you will need to use a `while` loop.

Comment: For future formatting reference: You can indent your code with four spaces (or just highlight and click the code formatting button `{}` at the top) to preserve your code's formatting insteading relying on `<br>` tags. Also you can surround code in your question with backticks (on the same line) to preserve formatting.

Comment: You should stop using the old and insecure `mysql_*`-functions. They were deprecated all the way back in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. If you're still able to use them, it means that you're writing code for an unsupported and obsolete version of PHP, which is bad. Use Mysqli or, even better, PDO instead.

Comment: Another option would be using the mysqli_fetch_all function More.https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_all.asp

Comment: @GeorgeSun Thank you for your help. Of course i used while to loop my array, but rank not show 1 , 2 but just 1..

Comment: @JNevill thank you for your help, in my complete code i success full echo my array, but rank value just show 1, not 1 2..

Comment: @M.Eriksson thank you for your help, i will edit my question with my completely code..

Comment: The column name is subjects, but you use subject in the query.